# Python Reading From File Putting Extra Mark and Pharanthesis

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, io

my input file content is

```
12sljg1', 'kf
[]
             ffdasfsdfdsf
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am reading these lines into a list and print them with code:

```
lines = [line.splitlines() for line in open(r'C:\Users\BerkayS\Desktop\testfile.txt', 'r')]

print(lines[0:2])
```

Output is:

```
[["12sljg1', 'kf"], ['[]']]
```

Why it is putting quotation mark (") to start and end of the member at first position which is

> 12sljg1', 'kf

?

Comment: Because it is a string.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Because the first string already has a single quote in it, so it can't use the single quote to denote it as a string without escaping them.

Comment: Thanks James thats exactly what i want to learn. @LutzHorn [] is not a string too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print statement is using default formating for this type of structure.
Your structure is List 
So python will indicate this by adding [] to representation
Additionaly to show members of list and indicate its type again its add "" to show You its string

You must use some formating to ommit this.

Answer (score 0):

That's how the Python output represents strings

Comment: @pacholik: The only thing the OP asked was "why" the quotation marks were in the output, so this is a perfectly acceptable answer.